# Change status code of Django CBV response if form is not valid

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Using Django's class-based views, how can I set the status code to 400 when returning a response if the form is not valid? This is easy enough in a functional view, but the CBV responds w/ a 200 status regardless of form validity.

```
class CRMContactsAdd(CreateView):

    model = models.Contact
    fields = ['name','job_title','phone_number','email_address','notes']
    template_name = 'crm/add_contact.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('CRM-list')+"?show_modal_url="+reverse('CRM-contacts',args=())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        cd = super(CRMContactsAdd,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cd['company'] = get_object_or_404(models.Company,pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        cd['title'] = "Add contact to %s" % (cd['company'].name)
        return cd

    def form_valid(self, form):
        contact = form.save(commit=False)
        contact.company = get_object_or_404(models.Company,pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(CRMContactsAdd,self).form_valid(form)
```

The reason why I'd want to do this is that I can easily use status codes to say whether or not, with a form in a modal window, reload the top level window or update the modal w/ the response of submitting the form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override `form_invalid()` to change the status code of the response:

```
class CRMContactsAdd(CreateView):
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super().form_invalid(form)
        response.status_code = 400
        return response
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!